# Why does this promise resolve twice, once when resolving normally and once with promise.all?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to retrieve images a url and run a function when all the images have been loaded (formatImages). To achieve this I have created a promise to monitor the image loading process and resolve when completed. To ensure that all the images have loaded I then run promise.all on a list of the created promises to check if they have all resolved. The issue is that this seems to resolve the promise twice resulting in duplicate images. I would've expected it to work where the promise resolves and promise.all CHECKS if they have resolved rather than trying to resolve the promise itself. If this is the correct functionality of promise.all. How can I add the promises to the list without running that promise.

I have attempted to rewrite the promise so that .then and .catch are within the images function. This did nothing and caused the values returned from promise.all to be undefined?

```
let promiseList = []
let loadedImages = 0;

let image = function(i) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = `https://source.unsplash.com/random?${imageTopic}/sig${i}`;
        img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));
        img.addEventListener('error', () => {
            reject(new Error(`Failed to load image's URL: ${url}`));
        });
    });
}

for (let i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
    promiseList.push(image(i))
    promiseList[i].then(img => {
        mosaic.appendChild(img);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    });
}

Promise.all(promiseList).then((values) => {
    images = document.querySelectorAll(".mosaic img");
    formatImages();
    console.log(values)
});
```

Expected Result: The promise resolves ONCE, with the .then of promise.all being what runs when all the promises in the promiseList have resolved.

Actual Result: The promise resolves twice, there are also other issues such as the return promise.all being undefined.

Comment: If you want Promise.all to wait for the `.appendChild` in the callback, you need to `promiseList.push(image(i).then(...))`. "this seems to resolve the promise twice resulting in duplicate images" is confusing and not clear what you're trying to ask.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. It seem that the resolve function of the promise is being called twice, when I only want it to happen once.

Comment: A promise can only ever resolve once, so whatever the issue is, it is not a promise resolving more than once. It's hard to sync the problem you are describing with the code you are showing because the code has a lot of unknowns (like `mosaic `, `formatImages`, you're saving `images` in the Promise.all callback, but don't anything, etc ). It would help if you could make an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Interesting, so what do you think could be causing it to append 2 images twice. Does promise.all resolve the promises?

Comment: "It seem that the resolve function of the promise is being called twice" - Be specific. What does this mean? What are you seeing and what are you expecting to see? Add console logging to your code to check your assumptions. You assume a promise is getting resolved twice but have no reason to think this

Comment: The reason I think the promise is getting resolved twice, keeping in mind I have a very limited understanding of promises is because the .then of the promise is to append the image to the container. Since there are 2 of the same image being appended I did assume that the .then was executing twice and therefore the promise is being resolved twice. This may be wrong. My console logging indicates that the .then is being run twice. When the promise.all is commented out the issue is not present but the format function could be run before all the images are loaded hence why I used promise.all.

Comment: A promise wont ever resolve twice ... the code `promiseList[i].then` runs when the promise resolves, and the code `Promise.all(promiseList).then((values) => {` runs when all such promises resolve. You have multiple "listeners" for the one resolve, but it still resolves, just the once ... at `img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));` (even if `load` were to be called more than once, the promise would still only be resolved the first time)

Comment: perhaps you wanted to do something like `promiseList.push(image(i).then(img => {
        mosaic.appendChild(img);
        return img;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    }));` - that way, Promise.all will not "trigger" until all `mosaic.appendChild(img)` have been completed rather than when all `image(i)` have been completed